# Problema al eliminar activity_main.xml por error

Tags: android-studio

tenia puesto un codigo en el **activity_main.xml** que estaba en otro color, al pulsar la luz para ver que información mostraba, me creo otro xml con el nombre **activity_main.xml(v21)**.

Elimine este segundo xml que se creó, y desaparecio tambien el primero activity_main.xml, así que volvi a crear activity_main.xml y le puse el codigo que tenia.

Pero cuando voy a probar la aplicación me muestra este mensaje de erro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si con esta captura del error puede serviros para ver dónde está el problema, el Logcat no sé qué texto copiar para ponerlo aquí, porque hay mucho.

Comment: Intentaste consultar el historial local?

Comment: Hola Ruslan, lo que estoy intentando es saber donde esta el historial local

Comment: vale ya lo encontre, pero no me dice mucho, que tengo que mirar ahi ?

Comment: si revirtiendo a una vesión anterior se soluciona

Comment: Vale Ruslan creo que ya he visto la diferencia que hay entre los dos paneles que muestra, he comparado y he visto que en el toolbar tengo puesto **AppTheme.FondoMenu"** y antes tenia **ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark** lo he cambiado y a funcionado pero lo gracioso es que he vuelto a dejar como lo tenia cuando daba el error, y ahora ya no lo da

Comment: tal vez fue un problema de que la compilación ser quedó en caché del IDE, avísanos si tienes algún otro problema.

Comment: ¿Al *pulsar la luz*?

Comment: jeje, si A. Cedano, es que me expreso muy bien, quería decir es la bombilla esa que aparece en el lado izquierdo  http://funkyimg.com/i/2CMeB.png

Comment: Ah, ah ok. Pensé que habías pulsado el interruptor y se había dañado tu app. :) Me alegro de que se haya resuelto.

Comment: Gracias, es aquí  http://funkyimg.com/i/2CMeB.png, bueno voy a seguir con un problema más grave que tengo, a ver si mañana os pido ayuda a ver si se consigue solucionar, porque eso sí que me está frenando para no poder terminar la aplicación, la dichosa flecha atras me trae por el camino de la amargura